# How do I test a function which returns a function using Mocha, Sinon, and Chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a function which returns another function of the same name. Inside the second function, functions from other modules are being used. I just want to test whether the functions from other modules are being called.

Here is some code to clarify what I mean:

```
exports.getCache = function (model) {
  return function getCache (req, res){
     //some code
     key = utils.uniqueKey(model, id)
     //some code

     res.json(result);
  }
}
```

I want to check if uniqueKey is being called and if res.json is being called.

Any help at all is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
sinon.spy(utils, 'uniqueKey')
```

in your test file, probably inside `beforeEach` function. Then it should be easy to check with `chai.expect` function whenever it was called:

```
expect(utils.uniqueKey.called).to.be.true();  
expect(utils.uniqueKey.calledWith({modelValue: 'value'}, 'someId')).to.be.true();
```

where `{modelValue: 'value'}` and `'someId'` are the actual values of `model` and `id` variables.

Comment: That does make sense. However, I am testing in a different file called test.js. So when I call the getCache function, it will call utils from that file rather then the spy that I created in test.js. How can I work around that?

Cheers,
Harit

Comment: U can mock all the utils object in such manner: `utils = {uniqueKey: sinon.spy()};` in your test file.

Answer (score 0):

To make your component testable you have to make its dependencies injectable. As I see your code depends on `utils`. To properly mock this you can't just `require('utils')`, you have to implement some way to wire up dependencies. Using some DI library, or just extend public interface of your component:

```
var utils;

module.exports.dependencies = function (_utils) {
    utils = _utils;
};

module.exports.getCache = function (model) {
    key = utils.uniqueKey(model, id);
};
```

Then in productive code before using bootstrap your component calling `component.dependencies(require('utils'))`. In test case you can pass there a spy: `component.dependencies(spy);`